# Receive from API Map/HashMap

Tags: api, dictionary, hashmap, retrofit

Hi guys i just updated my code, now "everything" works nice, i got the connection and i recive the item, i would like to add it to a MAP, can someone help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String ENDPOINT_URL = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/";
    private TextView resultTv;
    private GetwilliamData getwilliamData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ENDPOINT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        getwilliamData = retrofit.create(GetwilliamData.class);

        Button allbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getallBtn);
        allbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadwilliam();
            }

        });


        Button onebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oneBtn);
        onebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadwilliam();

            }

        });

        resultTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTV);
    }

    private void loadwilliam() {
        Call<SummonerData> call = getwilliamData.all();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SummonerData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SummonerData> call, Response<SummonerData> response) {
                System.out.println("HERE --------------------> " + call.request().url());
                SummonerData result = response.body();
                System.out.println("here ------------------------> " + response.body().getwilliam().getName());
                displayResult(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SummonerData> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("kdfsssssssssv -----------------> " + t.getMessage());
                System.out.println("HERE ---------------------> testing");
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayResult(SummonerData sd) { //throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException

        if (sd != null) {

            william r = sd.getwilliam();
            Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Field[] declaredFields = r.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : declaredFields) {
               // try {
                    //result.put(field.getName(), field.get(r));
                    result.put(field.getName(), field.getName());
                result.
             //   }
             //   catch (IllegalAccessException e){
                    result.put("Error", "reflection error");


             //   }
            }
            System.out.println(("--------------------------> id: " + result.get("id") ));
            resultTv.setText("id: " + result.get("id") );

        } else {
            resultTv.setText("Error asd");
        }

    }

}
```

its here the problem

```
private void displayResult(SummonerData sd) { //throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException

if (sd != null) {

    william r = sd.getwilliam();
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Field[] declaredFields = r.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
       // try {
            //result.put(field.getName(), field.get(r));
            result.put(field.getName(), field.getName());
        result.
     //   }
     //   catch (IllegalAccessException e){
            result.put("Error", "reflection error");


     //   }
    }
    System.out.println(("--------------------------> id: " + result.get("id") ));
    resultTv.setText("id: " + result.get("id") );

} else {
    resultTv.setText("Error asd");
}
```

i know its not working/bad coding i was running some tests..

Extra:

SummonerData

```
public class SummonerData {
@SerializedName("william")
@Expose
    private william william;
/**
* 
* @return
* The william
*/
    public william getwilliam() {
    return william;
}
/**
* 
* @param william
* The william
*/
    public void setwilliam(william william) {
    this.william = william;
}
```

William

```
public class william {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("profileIconId")
@Expose
private Integer profileIconId;
@SerializedName("summonerLevel")
@Expose
private Integer summonerLevel;
@SerializedName("revisionDate")
@Expose
private long revisionDate;

/**
 * 
 * @return
 * The id
 */
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param id
 * The id
 */
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 * The profileIconId
 */
public Integer getProfileIconId() {
    return profileIconId;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param profileIconId
 * The profileIconId
 */
public void setProfileIconId(Integer profileIconId) {
    this.profileIconId = profileIconId;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 * The summonerLevel
 */
public Integer getSummonerLevel() {
    return summonerLevel;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param summonerLevel
 * The summonerLevel
 */
public void setSummonerLevel(Integer summonerLevel) {
    this.summonerLevel = summonerLevel;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 * The revisionDate
 */
public long getRevisionDate() {
    return revisionDate;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param revisionDate
 * The revisionDate
 */
public void setRevisionDate(long revisionDate) {
    this.revisionDate = revisionDate;
}
```

GetWilliamData

```
public interface GetwilliamData {


@GET("api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/william?api_key=105bf501-8748-4e05-a913-ec570428375f")
Call<SummonerData> all();

@GET("api/lol/{server}/v1.4/summoner/by-name/{name}?api_key=105bf501-8748-4e05-a913-ec570428375f")
Call<william> select(@Path("name") String name);
```

}

Thanks for your attetion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
william r = sd.getwilliam();
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Field[] declaredFields = william.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            result.put(field.getName(), field.get(r));
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e){
            result.put("Error", "reflection error");


       }
    }
```

Comment: Ow sorry! I'm new here! It's done!
Btw do you know/have an ideia how can pick and image from code?
I mean, i'm using this with RIOT API and i would like to do like a match history (like this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/07df9147d46946d19ca9e3642046191c.png)
and i'm trying with this:
https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/static-data
But have no ideia how to start/do ....

Or should i open a new topic for that?
Thanks!

Comment: @William you need to read on the docs well as questions will only help in case you are able to infer what these docs says but stuck somewhere. btw   you may find picasso image library useful.